# How to secure a password in Delphi exe?

Tags: delphi, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

How to secure/hide authentication username/password of a database (The data base is on server - MySQL) ?
The in client side encryption doesn't look like the ideal solution because the key can be found.
I thought about storing the encrypted username/password in the EXE so the description will happen in the server side, this is the best method i found.
What's the best way to secure authentication information and if the method i found is good how can i do it ?

Comment: it depends on the database you use. Common solutions are using ODBC data sources (which have to be created by your installer). If you communicate via the internet then using a data layer (exposed via REST API) on the server side is a wise thing to do...

Comment: The data base is MySQL, do i need to use PHP to add that data layer on the server @whosrdaddy ?

Comment: You can program the data tier in any language you like. If you want to use Delphi, take a good look at [Synopse Mormot Framework](https://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3+Framework)

Comment: Is this a corporate application?

Comment: @whosrdaddy thank you, just please if you can explain a little that would be appreciated, no it's not a corporate application

Comment: Hard to give you any specific advise as I don't know the details of your application. Here are some very simple rules: Never ever put your MySQL server on the internet (you will be hacked). Don't use your database password on the client layer, you do that in the service/data layer (which is server side) Use a custom authentication scheme for you clients (not related to your database)

Comment: @whosrdaddy what do u mean by " Never ever put your MySQL server on the internet (you will be hacked)", i have to put is in a hosting (on server) because this is more secure and i use it for licencing so i have to put it on a server

Comment: Sure, do whatever you want, I think I made my point...

Answer (score 2):

The best is to switch to a n-Tier architecture, e.g. defining a REST server, and keep the MySQL password in it.

Otherwise, you may encrypt the password on the client side. If you hardcode the password in the executable, it would be easy to find out - at least encrypt it. You may use a naive *Rot13* or *xor* or similar, but better use a safer alternative, e.g. using Windows password DPAPI encryption or something like our safe [CryptDataForCurrentUser()](https://synopse.info/files/html/api-1.18/SynCrypto.html#CRYPTDATAFORCURRENTUSER) function.

Comment: i want to hide the password even from the user, the password is for a database where i manage licensing

Comment: @Kimber: It is easy to reverse engineer any application, find out the db credentials hidden in application and then the whole DB will be exposed, bad idea....

Comment: @Kimber Just encrypt the DB password in a settings files, as I wrote. But this is unsafe: better switch to n-Tier, with n>2. :)